# Android logging csv data to SD card

Tags: android, csv, sd-card, export-to-csv

I have been been loitering on this site for weeks and have found it invaluable, however I am now stuck and need some pointers please. I am writing an app to create a .txt file on the sd card and then append csv data to it. Here is my code so far:

```
private void LogData() {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, "/DataLogger/my_file.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (file.exists()) try {
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    writer.write("Example");
                    writer.write("\n");
                    writer.write("Text");
                    writer.write("\n");
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

From the above, I anticipated that on calling "LogData()" for the first time an empty .txt file would be created and then subsequent runs would populate it. Instead nothing happens at all (no file is created). Prior to the above I have tried every piece of example code on creating a .txt file and nothing work. I am absolutely lost - please help!

And yes, I have added the following to the manifest :-)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For information, I am running lollipop 5.0.2 on a Moto G and I am very new to coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is possible that the directory /DataLogger does not exist and you need to create it

Comment: Move that code from the catch block to the try block.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I found the issue - it was creating files but they weren't visible until I checked using file explorer (rather than via the laptop with USB). I have since found that this is a common android bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
      try {
            file.createNewFile();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new   FileWriter(file));
            writer.write("Example");
            writer.write("\n");
            writer.write("Text");
            writer.write("\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks peterho, although my code now creates a new file, it only writes one initial string, rather than continually appending data as it is generated. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I was not using the constructor correctly. Correct code:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

When you open a file using the FileWriter constructor that only takes in a File, it will overwrite what was previously in the file. Supplying the second parameter as true tells the FileWriter that you want to append to the end of it. Thanks to @nicholas.hauschild for his answer 4 years ago...